# Header appears instead of array[position] item inside listview which has more than a row type

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, row, adapter

Suppose I have this String array :

```
public static final String[] countries = {"USA", "Argentina", "Ecuador", "Brazil",  "Canada", "Senegal", "Ghana", "Nigeria", "Togo", "South Africa"};
```

I am passing this array to my custom adapter which extends baseAdapter. While overriding the `getItemViewType(int position)` method, I am moding (%) my array with 5, to get the array into two categories, as I want to insert the headers "America" and "Asia" above each set of county.

I am able to do so, and the app is technically running (no errors, no compile fails), however,
wherever there will be header before the country which resulted in 0 for the mod, in this case, USA and SENEGAL, the headers appear INSTEAD of the countries, thus There is the header 'America' and below the 4 countires (USA omitted appear).

I want the header to appear before the name of the country, that is, before the USA and SENEGAL. Totaling the number of rows for the list to 12 (the array is 10).

If code is needed, I shall supply you.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @iambmelton I edited my question, have a look.